# Canvas 3D drawing using both 2D and 3D context

Tags: html, opengl-es, canvas, webgl

Since the webgl/opengl doesn't support text drawing, so it possible to draw 3D object using 3D context and text drawing using 2D context ?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

No, unfortunately not.

The [HTML 5 spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#dom-canvas-getcontext) says that if you call `getContext` on a canvas element that is already in a different [context mode](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#concept-canvas-context-mode) and the two contexts are not compatible then return `null`.

Unfortunately "webgl" and "2d" canvases are not compatible and thus you will get `null`:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('my-canvas');
var webgl = canvas.getContext("webgl"); // Get a 3D webgl context, returns a context
var twod = canvas.getContext("2d"); // Get a 2D context, returns null
```

Answer (score 21):

As stated, you cannot do this.

However you can put one canvas on top of another and draw to them separately. I've done this before and it can work out quite well.

Comment: For more info, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008635/html5-canvas-element-multiple-layers

Answer (score 6):

Create the text as a texture using canvas 2D, then render it in 3D. See [here](http://murfy.de/read/webgl-text-rendering) for a tutorial.

Comment: But if the text is dynamically updating, then text rendering will become slow.

Comment: Text rendering is slow anyway.

Answer (score 4):

What I've been doing, whether I just need troubleshooting feedback or 2D text content on a 3D canvas, is just use CSS to put some HTML elements on top of the canvas.

You can make a canvas and a group of text fields share the same space, and ensure that the text fields are on top as follows:

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  <div id="controlsContainer">
    <label>Mouse Coordinates</label>
      <div>
        <label for="xPos">X</label>
        <span id="xPos"></span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="yPos">Y</label>
        <span id="yPos"></span>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
canvas {
    margin: 0px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}

#container {
  position: relative;
}

#controlsContainer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  z-index: 3;
}

  #controlsContainer div {
    padding-left: 8px;
  }

  #controlsContainer label {
    color: white;
    z-index: 4;
  }

  #controlsContainer span {
    color: white;
    z-index: 4;
  }
```

The `z-index` will ensure which elements are in front, and `position: relative` for the container and `position: absolute`, in coordination with the `top` and `left` for the controls will ensure that they share the same space.

I have been having very good luck with this, and the troubleshooting feedback is invaluable.

[image]

An example of the Javascript (ES6 in this case) is:

```
let xPos = document.getElementById("xPos");
let yPos = document.getElementById("yPos");
let x = event.clientX - containerDiv.offsetLeft -parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(pageBody).getPropertyValue("margin-left"));
let y = event.clientY - containerDiv.offsetTop - parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(pageBody).getPropertyValue("margin-top"));
xPos.innerText = x;
yPos.innerText = y;
```

which I've placed in a mousemove handler.