# HTML5 Canvas layer issue

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have similar issue with layers as described here [html5 - canvas element - Multiple layers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008635/html5-canvas-element-multiple-layers)

But, accepted answer doesn't work for me, as for layer1 I have rendered image (drawImage)

And second layer - layer2 (gradient) always **under** layer1.

Sample code:

```
    canvas = document.getElementById("layer1");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var img = new Image();
    img.src = "/img/img.png";
    img.onload = function() {
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    };

    canvas2 = document.getElementById("layer2");
    ctx2 = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var my_gradient = ctx2.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 400);
    my_gradient.addColorStop(0, "black");
    my_gradient.addColorStop(1, "white");
    ctx2.fillStyle = my_gradient;
    ctx2.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 555);
```

HTML:

```
    <canvas id="layer1" width="1000" height="1000" style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 0;"></canvas>
    <canvas id="layer2" width="1000" height="1000" style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 1;"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting `ctx2` to layer1's context:

```
ctx2 = canvas.getContext("2d");
```

Of course, since the image loads asynchronously, the `onload` event fires after you've already drawn the gradient, and it gets drawn on the same canvas.

Comment: Yes, you right. It works now. But it's strange, as layer2 has z-index more over.
Any way, it works now, thanks!