# How to avoid text overlap in html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am taking text from user and displaying on canvas. Again if the user enters another text on the same position, then the text is getting overlapped and not replaced. How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: can you show an example?

Comment: How much effort you put to debug this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543687/how-do-i-clear-text-from-the-canvas-element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Use `clearRect` and clear!

```
context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you are actually painting the scene on the canvas.

What you could do to clear that text is:

- If you are tracking the elements drawn on the canvas (using objects and arrays), like how object-oriented canvas frameworks do, remove that object tracking the text. During the next redraw of the scene (or a partial), the text won't get drawn.
- or, for a quick and easy way to do it, draw a rectangle over the text that matches the background. It's similar to placing correction fluid over ink on paper.