# Save many canvas element as image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have 3 layers of canvas - 1 is matrix, 2 & 3 is graphics, how to preserve them in one image?

```
<div style="position: relative;">
 <canvas id="matix" width="100" height="100" 
   style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 0;"></canvas>
 <canvas id="layer1" width="100" height="100" 
   style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 0;"></canvas>
 <canvas id="layer2" width="100" height="100" 
   style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 1;"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want them combined into 1 image on layered on top of each other or side by side?

Comment: combined into 1 image on layered on top of each other

Comment: How did you implemented layers? Are they separated canvas elements? First layer is matrix of what (do you mean pixel data?)? Is it something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008635/html5-canvas-element-multiple-layers

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can draw one canvas into another with `ctx.drawImage(other_canvas,0,0)`

If you do that in the right order, you will have all the canvas contents correctly layered in one of them.

If you want to *save* the image, you can call `canvas.toDataURL()` to get the contents as a base64 encoded PNG file.