# How can I save div as image at client side where div contains one or more than one HTML5 canvas elements?

Tags: image, html, canvas, save, client-side

Div 'canvasesdiv' element contains three HTML5 canvases.

```
<div style="position: relative; width: 400px; height: 300px;" id="canvasesdiv">
    <canvas width="400" height="300px" style="z-index: 1; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;" id="layer1" />
    <canvas width="400" height="300px" style="z-index: 2; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;" id="layer2"/>
    <canvas width="400" height="300px" style="z-index: 3; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;" id="layer3"/>
</div>
```

How can I save an image combining all canvases present inside the div 'canvasesdiv' at client side using JavaScript?

Comment: new Image() + magic + localStorage?

Comment: I'm working with HTML/HTML5 and JavaScript only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very similar to a previous question that I answered:
[save-many-canvas-element-as-image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750580/save-many-canvas-element-as-image/3797989#3797989)

In summary: draw all of the canvases to one of them and then get the image via `toDataURL()`

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to use Ajax query for some serverside operations.
A canvas can be exported in png using [Apache Batik](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/tools/rasterizer.html) with `exec('java -jar...')`

The rest is algorithmic.

Comment: It’s not an expected answer. Sorry. I don't have any option to do any server side job. And my question is purely about client side. So it does not help me.