# HTML 5 Canvas and Javascript: Combining layered canvases

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I wanted to combine images from different canvases (layered on top of each other using z-index) to export as one single image.

Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I save div as image at client side where div contains one or more than one HTML5 canvas elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880330/how-can-i-save-div-as-image-at-client-side-where-div-contains-one-or-more-than-on)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Save many canvas element as image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750580/save-many-canvas-element-as-image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same :

[How can I save div as image at client side where div contains one or more than one HTML5 canvas elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880330/how-can-i-save-div-as-image-at-client-side-where-div-contains-one-or-more-than-on)

[Save many canvas element as image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750580/save-many-canvas-element-as-image/3797989#3797989)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the context.getImageData() and context.putImageData().  I haven't tried that in Javascript before, but it shouldn't be that difficult.

[HTML Canvas 2D Context](http://dev.w3.org/html5/2dcontext/#pixel-manipulation)