# How can I save multiple divs as an image?

Tags: javascript, html, png, image, jpeg

I'm trying to build an interface for the user, so he can choose or pick colored eyes, skin, etc., of a model. I'm really on my way with `div`s and CSS. I'm using Ajax for loading images into the `div`s.

My problem is that I need to offer a option to the user so he can save the image as a JPEG or PNG file.

Looking around, I found canvas HTML5 stuff on Stack Overflow, but it's not compatible with Internet Explorer,

- *[Create an Image of a DIV in JavaScript (GIF/PNG)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/839216/create-an-image-of-a-div-in-javascript-gif-png)*
- *[How can I save div as image at client side where div contains one or more than one HTML5 canvas elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880330/how-can-i-save-div-as-image-at-client-side-where-div-contains-one-or-more-than-on)*

I need help to find something compatible with all browsers.

I also found this JavaScript code:

```
button = document.createElement("img");
button.src = "http://example.com/livechart.gif?interval=15"
```

But I don't know much about the `createElement` method.

I know CSS, but JavaScript is beyond my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this on the browser, you must do it on the server.

see: [Convert web page to image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/968201/convert-web-page-to-image)

Comment: Nice i look into the topic, but, im wondering its there a tutorial or something for the use of Imagemagick cause im really starting. but i will learn  ihope :D

Comment: This is a complex issue, not something for beginners.

Comment: well not that king of beginner.. anyway thanks for your help.. ill keep looking and reading.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could do that with [HTML canvas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canvas_element) and some JavaScript: *[Canvas2Image : Saving Canvas data to image file](http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/)*.

Comment: Canvas can't render HTML, yet

Comment: everything is possible with javascript http://onepixelahead.com/2010/05/12/how-to-use-html5-canvas-with-ie6-ie7-and-ie8/  you might eventurn ie 6 in a good browser

Comment: jajaja well that would be great!!, thanks for your answers i need to be friendly with common browsers

Comment: Man this is what i neeeed thaaaanks!! its a shame it wont work on IE =(  http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/

Comment: Thanks!!!!! http://onepixelahead.com/2010/05/12/how-to-use-html5-canvas-with-ie6-ie7-and-ie8/

Answer (score 0):

You want to take *screenshot* of the browser?  Well, there are lot of ways you could *try*, but all of them would be browser-specific.  The most reliable would be to just tell the user to make a screenshot with the OS.  On a Mac it's Command-Shift-4, then space; on a PC, it it's ALT-PrtScr, I think.

Comment: But that sucks.. i wont tell my user to use paint or somethig to cut the image of the div  in the screenshot jajaja.. i just need to save a DIV of that html, as an image, with javascript or something. thats my question how.. i see a lot of apss, that saves the final result as an image.. how do the do it whit javascript?

Comment: They *don't* do it with Javascript.  Not only with Javascript anyway; they have sophisticated back-end systems for rendering the image.  Just because something is possible doesn't mean it's easy.

Comment: well hope u people get happier.. if you see the next answer you can see what intelligence can do for people! thanks to user901215 for his answers..