# How to save the composite of many layers (div) stack one over the other

Tags: jquery, image, jpeg

I have 10 layers of PNG with different z-index pile on each other... I don't used canvas because of the shortcoming... So that pile should be flatten and save (exported) as one single jpg... how i do that.. with jquery...

Question #1 - is it possible to merge all layer (div) into one ?
Question #2 - is it possible to take all div and merge it to a canvas ?
Question #3 - if canvas is used, is it the only solution ?

I have found that answer : [Save many canvas element as image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750580/save-many-canvas-element-as-image) feel pretty confident to make it work... unless better answer.. it will be that !

Comment: You need canvas or a server-side language to do that.

Comment: can you generate a canvas based of a stack of div on the fly ?

Comment: Not without violating "I don't used canvas because of the shortcoming"

Comment: Use the PrtScn button? What you want should be done with php on the server side or with canvas.

Comment: saving canvas in IE dont work.. maybe saving flattend div will ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

having no better answer, i have found that : html2canvas... http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/