# HTML5 Canvas eraser

Tags: html, canvas

There's a way of implementing an eraser (other than using a white pencil?).

I'm using layering, I have an image below the canvas, so, if eraser paints white, the user is going to notice since the below image isn't solid white.

Answer (score 5):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Compositing

Actually the function is:

```
function eraser(){
    context.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";  
    context.strokeStyle = "rgba(255,255,255,1)";
}
```

And you can go back to source-over.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, you can use multiple `<canvas>` objects drawn over each other, then erase from the top canvas to reveal the image beneath. See: [html5 - canvas element - Multiple layers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008635/html5-canvas-element-multiple-layers)

Answer (score 2):

```
function eraser()
{                                
context.strokeStyle = "rgb(255, 255, 255)";
context.globalCompositeOperation = "copy";  
context.strokeStyle = ("rgba(255,255,255,255)"); /* or */ context.fillStyle = "rgba(255,0,0,0)";
}
```

both worked in my case!

Comment: this does not remotely work. [proof](https://jsfiddle.net/greggman/jo5nqrzs/)

Answer (score 0):

Code for transparent eraser using globalCompositeOperation "destination-out" and "source-over"

```
var handleMouseMove = function (event) {
    midPt = new createjs.Point(oldPt.x + stage.mouseX>>1, oldPt.y+stage.mouseY>>1);

   if(curTool.type=="eraser"){

      var tempcanvas = document.getElementById('drawcanvas');
      var tempctx=tempcanvas.getContext("2d");
      tempctx.beginPath();
      tempctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";   
      tempctx.arc(midPt.x, midPt.y, 20, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);     
      tempctx.fill();
      tempctx.closePath();
      tempctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
      drawingCanvas.graphics.clear();

      // keep updating the array for points 
      arrMidPtx.push(midPt.x);
      arrMidPty.push(midPt.y);
      stage.addChild(drawingCanvas);
      stage.update();

    }
```

I have used easeljs here however the code is independent from it and can be integrated with any canvas html5 drawing javascript code

Answer (score -2):

set the pencil color to transparent:

```
context.fillStyle = "rgba(255,0,0,0)";
```

in `rgba()` format, the last one is the alpha channel, 0 is totally transparent

Comment: It does't work. The 'eraser pencil' stills draw on red (the color of the actual drawing pencil).

Comment: try setting the color as simply "transparent" (http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-color/#transparent), or maybe `strokestyle` instead of `fillstyle`

Comment: =( Nothing. I already tried both context.strokeStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0)"; and context.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0)";. Any ideas?