# Eraser Effect Using CSS or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

Is anyone aware of any css or javascript that creates an effect of gradually erasing text on a web page the same way a chalkboard eraser would erase writing on a chalkboard?

Thanks.

Comment: interesting idea, but what have you got so far?

Comment: What do you mean by `the same way a chalkboard eraser would erase writing`?

Comment: For fun you can (read inefficient) animate background-image gradients! Quick demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MncSg/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've made a little demo which uses a gradient, box-shadow and keyframe animation. The code is below and you can see it in action at http://dabblet.com/gist/2722829

```css
.parent {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 125px auto;
  padding: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.eraser {
  left:-30%;
  top: 8px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 130%;
  border-radius: 135px/65px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 100px 50px rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  background: radial-gradient(#fff, rgba(255, 255, 255, .95));
  animation: erase 4s ease-out;
}
@keyframes erase {
  from {left: -170%;}
  to {left: -30%;}
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <p>Biscuit danish icing halvah jelly beans jelly beans powder liquorice sugar plum. 
  Pie marzipan toffee donut chocolate dragée topping caramels. 
  Applicake wafer donut soufflé. Icing danish dessert icing carrot cake soufflé apple pie.
  </p>
  <div class="eraser"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: So cool @Ana. Thanks. I will work with it and try to tweak it using javascript to get the effect to happen onMouseover. I want to be able to erase text using the mouse controls.

Comment: The link is now broken

Comment: That's why it's great the code is still here.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this effect using a `canvas`. See:

- ["Erasing" in html5 canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328906/erasing-in-html5-canvas)
- [HTML5 Canvas eraser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790211/html5-canvas-eraser)

A simulated backspace effect on text only can be seen here: http://demos.frnzzz.com/typing/

Free-form erasing of any DOM element on the page would be difficult, since you can't remove part of an element nor is it easy to apply color to only part of an element.

You could simulate partial removal of an element by moving it outside a visible region or clipping it. This would probably only work with one axis at a time.

Lastly, there might be some combination of [CSS transforms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Using_CSS_transforms) and/or [CSS transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/CSS_transitions) which gives the effect you are seeking, but browser support is currently better for `canvas` than transforms/transitions, so you would probably be better served by using a `canvas`.

Comment: Thanks @TimMedora. Before I asked the question I did see both of the links you provided. I want to achieve an effect where you drag your mouse pointer across a chalkboard and erase what is on it. Probably need o do this in flash. But I was exploring to see if some of the new CSS offered a concept like this or to see if anyone did anything real creative via jQuery.

Comment: @Ana's solution would be my top choice if you don't need to support every browser (much cleaner than using Flash, but IE 7/8/9 don't work). You could probably write a solution which degrades nicely and just clips/hides in browsers which don't support transitions.