# how to copy another canvas's data on the canvas with getContext('webgl')?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, webgl

I have a canvas for showing medical image and I have another canvas for annotating images by draw shape or line.

when I draw a line on canvas#2 I want to copy drawn line on canvas#1 something like this:

```
  var context = canvas1.getContext('2d');
  context.drawImage(canvas2,0,0);
```

but because my canvas#1 has a getContext('webgl') I can't do that.

I mean how to simulate

```
  drawImage() for getcontext('webgl')?
```

I really appreciate any help or advice.

Regards;

Zohreh

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could just use the `toDataURL` method of the webgl canvas to convert it into an image. Then draw it on the 2d context.

```
ctx2D.drawImage(webGLCanvas.toDataURL("image/png"), 0, 0);
```

In this case I believe you might have to set the `preserveDrawingBuffer` propertie of the webgl canvas to true when initializing it.

```
...getContext("webgl", {preserveDrawingBuffer: true});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but I need completely Vice Versa. I want to copy image to canvas with contex('webgl').

Comment: Sorry I got it all wrong then. It's a bit more complicated, in this case you'd have to get the 2D canvas image through toDataURL and use it as a texture on a square plane and draw it on the openGL context maybe using an ortho projection matrix. But I'm not into OpenGL stuff so I can't really help you with that =/

Comment: I got empty image when try copy webgl to 2d.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a 2D canvas as the on-screen canvas, and draw the WebGL canvas to it when updating the WebGL canvas before drawing whatever annotations on.

```
drawWebGLStuff(webGLCtx);

// Copy image data of WebGL canvas to 2D canvas.
// This should be done right after WebGL rendering,
// unless preserveDrawingBuffer: true is passed during WebGL context creation,
// since WebGL will swap buffers by default, leaving no image in the drawing buffer,
// which is what we want to copy.
ctx2D.drawImage(webGLCanvas, 0, 0);

drawAnnotations(ctx2D);
```

(The annotations could be rendered each frame from a list of shapes or drawn to another offscreen canvas, which is then drawn to the main (on-screen) canvas similar to the WebGL canvas.)

Or you can simply [layer the canvases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008635/html5-canvas-element-multiple-layers) on the page with absolute positioning and `z-index`:

```
<div style="position: relative;">
   <canvas id="layer1" width="100" height="100" 
       style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 0;"></canvas>
   <canvas id="layer2" width="100" height="100" 
       style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 1;"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: this results in empty image copied

Comment: @MichaelKlishevich I updated my answer to mention the code order / `preserveDrawingBuffer` requirement

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with Emscripten, needed to copy WebGL canvas to another empty canvas.
I used this code but got empty screen.

```
var sourceCanvasWebGL = document.getElementById( "canvas" );
var destinationCanvas = document.getElementById( "canvasCopy" );
var destinationCanvasContext = destinationCanvas.getContext('2d');
destinationCanvasContext.drawImage(sourceCanvasWebGL, 0, 0);
```

After some googling ([Saving canvas to image via canvas.toDataURL results in black rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32556939/saving-canvas-to-image-via-canvas-todataurl-results-in-black-rectangle)) I figured out that because WebGL is using 2 buffers while drawing I am copying the old buffer with empty content.

Problem was solved by setting `preserveDrawingBuffer: true` in the code used to make WebGL drawing.

`sourceCanvasWebGL.getContext("webgl2", { preserveDrawingBuffer: true })`

P.S. As an alternative you could make an image copy right after rendering the canvas. If so you do not need preserveDrawingBuffer.