# add multiple different layers in canvas

Tags: canvas, paperjs

I am trying to add several multiple shapes in different colours in my HTML canvas using paper.js. Is there a way to do this without having several canvases? Is it possible to draw the shapes within one canvas? Here is what I have: https://jsfiddle.net/8hywopu8/1/

HTML:

```
<canvas id="bacterium"></canvas>

<canvas id="bacterium"></canvas>

<canvas id="bacterium"></canvas>

<canvas id="bacterium"></canvas>

<canvas id="bacterium"></canvas>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008635/html5-canvas-element-multiple-layers Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to draw multiple shapes in one canvas.
http://paperjs.org/examples/hit-testing/ is one of the examples.