# fabric canvas on top of another canvas

Tags: canvas, fabricjs

Is there a way to have two fabricJS canvases one top of each other? I want to be able to draw on both canvases, but I want my lines contained only on Canvas Top. Canvas Bottom will have labels that will not be able to be drawn on Canvas Top.

[Crude image of what I'm trying to go for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Lpyd.png)

I thought I could layer two canvases together, one on top of another using css:

```
<style>
.div {
    width: 1550px;
    height: 512px;
    border: solid 0px #4a7497;
    margin-top: -512px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    position: relative;
}
</style>

<canvas id="canvasBottom" width="1650" height="612"</canvas>
<canvas id="canvasTop" class="div" width="1550" height="512"></canvas>
```

My script just renders the bottom canvas. At this point, all i want to do is display both canvases but have my lines on canvas top.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var canvasBottom = new fabric.Canvas('canvasBottom', { selection: false, backgroundColor: 'black', targetFindTolerance: 20});
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvasTop', { selection: false, backgroundColor: 'white', targetFindTolerance: 20});

    canvas.setBackgroundImage('http://website/image/background.png', 
    canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));

    var grid = 15;
    var d = document,
    ge = 'getElementById';

    //draws vertical lines
    for (var i = 1; i <= (<?php echo $yLines; ?>); i++) {
        canvas.add(new fabric.Line([ i * grid+100, 0, i * grid+100, 612],{stroke: 'yellow',strokeWidth: 1}));
    }

    canvas.renderAll();
    canvasBottom.renderAll();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3008863/7132835

Comment: I can stack the canvas divs on top of each other, but once i start drawing on them, the divs show up one above the other

Answer (score 0):

As I shared information how to put layers using CSS from stackoverflow post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3008863/7132835 you need to do the same logic, but in addition you will need to add code below to your fabric canvas declaration:

```
var canvasBottom = new fabric.Canvas('layer1',{position: absolute});
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('layer2',{position: absolute});
```

You can add additional properties as a background, etc.