# How can I overlap 2 FabricJS canvases over each other?

Tags: html, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am using FrabricJS to make a customizable belt builder.

I have most of the code working, however for the life of me I cannot have the canvases overlapping each other.

I have already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45759866/fabric-canvas-on-top-of-another-canvas) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008635/html5-canvas-element-multiple-layers/3008863#3008863) codes, but either the canvas don't stack perfectely and they are slightly offset, and/or the rest of the code stops working.

You can find the whole code [here](https://github.com/Nobody-Inhere/BuildaBelt2)

I have tried using absolite positioning, as well as wrapping both canvases on their own individual divs, but no cigar.

Help please!

Comment: In your code sample, you have never used fabric/canvas

Comment: What do you mean by this? Where should I put that?