# Layering The Canvas Without Multiple Canvases

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, canvas, html5-canvas

There I am creating a stamp maker in `HTML`,`Jquery` and `javascript`. In the editor of my application image is adding to `HTML` canvas (simple) and also the text, I just create new line element and then append it to the canvas.But the problem is that I want my image to be in back of text. I **googled** it alot and also search `stackoverflow` I got the solution of creating multiple canvases but in last I have to download the canvas to file for user. There is the problem. And I want to export whole canvas along with text one and second image together.If I create seperate canvas for the text and another for image and give image one low zindex it would be fine but there will be one canvas to be exported as image.

**Link to multiple layers in canvas** [html5 - canvas element - Multiple layers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008635/html5-canvas-element-multiple-layers)

I am hopping that we would come up with an idea of how to download both canvases as an image or find a method to take image to back of the canvas.

Any answer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you store the text, second image and first image in variables, you could just draw them on the canvas in the order you prefer. This means that, whenever there's some change in the image or text, you should clean the canvas and redraw everything.

Also, you may be interested in [Compositing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Compositing), since it allows you to decide where a new object is drawn in relation to the existing drawing (on top, behind, etc.)