# How can I overlay a 3D object with given coordinate X,Y,Z on Canvas with three.js

Tags: three.js, tensorflow.js

My code return x,y,z with each keypoint and how can I overlay a 3D object on my Finger tip.
I had follow this https://discourse.threejs.org/t/setting-up-renderers-canvas-element-by-html-id/13213 but its still no work ! what i had is a black screen , i had  already remove line document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
[Image show keypoint on hand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lc8C.png)

Comment: If all you got is a black screen that sounds more like ThreeJS is not even starting or the render cycle not being called at all. Could you add a [minimally reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in Codepen or JSFiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3ntog9y2/, here is my code . I Cant render a box on my canvas !

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you obtain a 2D and 3D rendering context on the same canvas element which is not supported. More information about this topic here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5016197/5250847

The `three.js` scene in your fiddle can be fixed by commenting out `var context = canvas.getContext('2d');` and properly set the size of the WebGL renderer.

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p6fL0md5/1/